# how can I prove (∀ x, ¬ A x) → ¬ ∃ x, A x from principles in lean?

Tags: logic, set-theory, lean

I know that to prove : (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) the proof is:

```
theorem : (¬ ∀ x, p x) → (∃ x, ¬ p x) := 
begin
    intro nAxpx, 
    by_contradiction nExnpx,
    apply nAxpx,
    assume a,
    by_contradiction hnpa,
    apply nExnpx,
    existsi a,
    exact hnpa,
end
```

But I have no idea how to prove: `(∀ x, ¬ A x) → ¬ ∃ x, A x`

Comment: What did you try? Can you show the proof up until where you get stuck?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before you begin posting.

Comment: The question you know how to solve seems to be harder than the one you have no idea about. Do you understand the proof of the one you can solve?

Answer (score 2):

`¬ p x` is defined to be `p x → false`. This means that using `intro` works when your goal is `¬`.

so for example, the following works

```hs
example {α : Type} {A : α → Prop} : (∀ x, ¬ A x) → ¬ ∃ x, A x :=
begin
  intros h₁ h₂,

end
```

You can use the `cases` tactic to eliminate a proof of `∃ x, A x` into an `x` and a proof of `A x`. So `cases h₂ with x hx` works as the next line of the above proof. You should hopefully be able to fill in the remainder of the proof yourself after that.